# How to typespec sigils in elixir?

Tags: elixir

> the code was edited after the answer of Aleksei Matiushkin to include the @type

I'm trying to `typespec` a sigil specifically a Regex sigil but the current elixir doc don't specify how.

My code is close of:

```
defmodule M do
  @type pattern :: ??
  @type input :: String.t()
  @type current :: non_neg_integer()

  def tokenize_pattern(pattern, input, current) do
    # ...
  end
end
```

```sh
iex> M.tokenize_pattern(~r/[0-9]/u, "123 hello", 0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sigil `~Z` is just syntactic sugar for `sigil_Z` macro, one even might define their own sigils, so their types are implementation-specific.

Both `~r` and `~R` sigils [return the escaped result](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.10.4/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L5082-L5085) of a call to [`Regex.compile!/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Regex.html?#compile!/2) which is apparently [`Regex.t()`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Regex.html#t:t/0).

---

*Sidenote:* your code would not compile. You probably wanted to define `@spec` fot the function as

```rb
  @spec (pattern :: Regex.t(),
         input :: String.t(),
         current :: non_neg_integer()) :: any()
  def tokenize_pattern(pattern, input, current) do
    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you, before post this I didn't know that <Module>.t() is a common pattern to express constructor types

Comment: Welcome! There is no notion of constructor in Elixir though. It is the common pattern for structs.